# How to recursively parse nested lists?

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion

I try to parse tokens representing nested lists.

I've written parsing function using loop and recursion and it works:

```
const assert = require('assert');

function parse(parent, tokens) {

  while(tokens.length > 0) {
    let token = tokens.shift();

    switch(token) {
      case '(':
        let children = parse([], tokens);
        parent.push(children);
        break;
      case ')':
        return parent;
      default:
        parent.push(token);
        break;
    }
  }
  return parent;
}

let tokens = ['(', '(', 1, 2, ')', ')', '(', 1, ')', '(', ')'];
let list = parse([], tokens);

console.log(list);
assert.deepEqual(list, [[[1, 2]], [1], []]);
```

The version using only recursion doesn't work:

```
function parse(parent, tokens) {

  if(tokens.length > 0) {
    let token = tokens.shift();

    switch(token) {
      case '(':
        return parent.concat([parse([], tokens)]);
      case ')':
        return parent;
      default:
        return parse(parent.concat(token), tokens);
    }
  }
  else {
    return parent;
  }
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: You should at least try to hide the fact that you're trying to get other people to do your homework.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds too much like homework to me. Have you even tried something?

Comment: Not homework. I'm writing parser and I need it in functional style. Look my other question about tokenizer.

Comment: Moreover it's already working example. I just can't wrap my head how to rewrite it. It's simple now, because recursion goes as deep as parens are nested.

Comment: @Marina The whole point of recursion is that it doesn't matter how deep it is. You just keep calling the function every time the parentheses are are nested, and it does the right thing.

Comment: The point in code above is to unwind the recursion at correct time so the resulting data structure is also properly nested.

Answer (score 1):

When converting an iterative algorithm to recursive, you must take in account:

- The base case: A certain condition on which the method must not recurse.
- "Reduce" the parameters'  complexity before passing them to the recursive invocation.

In your case, it is easy because the `parse` method has already parameters for input and output, so you just have to convert it to recursive through following the preceding two rules.

About how to get the output:

- With explicit output accumulator parameter: This is the way you have it already.
- Without: Taking the output parameter to an instance variable of the class.

Comment: I get the impression you are trivialising posted code. It's already using recursion.

Comment: No, not at all. The point is to replace the `while` loop by a recursive call.